# Show attribute in product view

Tags: magento, view, attributes

I created a custom attibute that contains a string. Now, I want to display it on my product view pages, so I tried to edit the view.phtml file.

```
<?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name') ?>
```

I tried to do something similar, because the name is also just an attribute, but I don't know how to do it.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php echo $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('manufacturer')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product); ?>
```

just replace "manufacturer" with your Attribute Code

this code will work in view.phtml

Answer (score 1):

Please try this. Hope this will work for you.

```html
   
$attribute = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('CustomAttributeCode');
if ($attribute)
{
    echo $attribute_value = $attribute ->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);
}
```

Comment: i putted the piece of code into my view.phtml, but the code is directly written into the page insntead of the value of the attribute, did i forget anything? until now, it's not recognized as code. Sorry for those dumb questions but i'm a beginner :)